# How can we get the jenkins console output in a text file(workspace) including jenkins console output also

Tags: jenkins

**How can we get the jenkins console output in a text file (workspace) including jenkins console output also.**

Answer (score 2):

if you want just access the log and download it as a txt file to your workspace from the job's URL:

```
${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

On Linux, you can use `wget` to download it to your workspace

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

The actual log file on the file system is in the Master machine. You can find it under:

`$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild/log`

Comment: can you tell me how we can achieve by batch and powercell command

Comment: @abhisheknipunyou can insert this command `wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText`

Comment: ${BUILD_URL} will give url of build, right or we need to get url of console output by other way.

Comment: @abhisheknipun Please read answer carefully and try to practice. This exact give text file of console log. Replace `${BUILD_URL}` with actual build URL.

Comment: But, every time build number will change. So, How can we give dynamic url from jenkins using batch script or powercell and I also dont want to use jenkins credentials and console to workspace plugin.

Comment: `${BUILD_URL}/consoleText` requires authentication to access.

Comment: @EthanYang - do we have any way of knowing this user and cred?

Answer (score 0):

If the curl command isn't working for you due to user authentication issues, you can visit the `${BUILD_URL}/consoleText` URL in your browser, then press CTRL+S as the page is loading.